# How to build a program in Google Cloud build on a Windows Machine?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyinstaller, google-cloud-build

I have a python script which need to be converted into a windows executable. I am using pyinstaller to convert the script to a windows executable. As of now pyinstaller is not supporting Cross compilation, So I have to build the executables in a windows machine. I was able to succesfully build the python script to a windows executable using my local windows machine.

I want to automate this build flow using Google Cloud build. How can I do it ? Or Should I choose some other aproach/features in google cloud to build the application ?

Comment: Google Cloud Build does not support Windows. The build containers are Linux only. My only suggestion would be to launch a Compute Engine VM running Windows Server and run your build scripts there. GitHub has very good build systems. You can set up a self-hosted runner for Windows, Linux, and macOS. I wrote an article for Ubuntu. The steps are almost the same for Windows: https://www.jhanley.com/github-create-a-self-hosted-runner-hyper-v-plus-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by @JohnHanley, at this time build steps can only be run in Linux containers. However, some users use a `remote builder` to remote to any machine you want and run something from there that includes Windows machine.

Refer to this [Cloud Build Remote Build Step](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder) guide.